# Let Status Tray hide items by default whilst showing the tray of `network-manager-gnome` package

Tags: debian, xfce

For every signal strength percentage somehow there is a new item added to the Status tray history:

[image: Status tray settings showing many NetworkManager items for each individual signal strength percentage]

Besides of beeing probably unintended it is quite unfortunate as I'd like to have new items hidden by default whilst having the network applet shown always. But like this, everytime there is a new signal strength the icon is going to disappear. How do achieve what I want?